# Jboss Server with same port on the same machine

Tags: jboss

Can we run more than one instance of Jboss Server with same port on the same machine ? If yes how ?

Thanks
Amar

Comment: The quickest solution is to check it yourself, it requires minimal efforts. Also it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

of course the only way to have two services listening on the same port is to make sure that they bind on different IP addresses. If you consider acceptable configure multiple addresses on the same interface, simply start each instance of JBoss with the flag "`-b <address>`"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it if your machine has several network interfaces (IP addresses) and you bind each Jboss instance to one different IP. For example, if your machines has two network interfaces: 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2, you could run each instance with the command:

```
./run.sh -c instance1 -b 192.168.1.1
./run.sh -c instance2 -b 192.168.1.2
```

But the most common case is running several instances in the same machine using different ports each instance, you can achieve that with Jboss Ports Bindings.

Look for detailed info in this JBoss Web: [Configuring Multiple JBoss Instances On One Machine](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  All you need is to also run a Apache server instance and use it as a load balancer to a JBoss cluster and use the mod_proxy or mod_ajp plugin to load balance between multiple JBoss instances.  To spin up multiple instances of JBoss 5 or JBoss 6 on Windows , use [my script here](https://gist.github.com/4366912)   (but you will have to enhance the configuration yourself to enable clustering and the Apache load balancer).   Plus, my launch script requires you download stuff from the YAJSW server wrapper project.

I frequently run multiple jboss servers as a cluster and I always run a Apache server on port 80 and 443 that load balances to the JBoss instances.  [Here is am example post from my blog](http://thegreenoak.blogspot.com/2011/05/jboss-load-balanced-cluster-on.html).