# running different application on same port and machine in jboss 7.0.2

Tags: java, port, jboss7.x, server

I want to deploy two application on same Jboss server and same port number.
I am confused that, is that possible and if yes then how it can be done .

I am using jboss 7.0.2

please help

Comment: You have Two WAR or Two EAR?

Answer (score 1):

You can run as many applications on one port as you like.
As long as they are bound to different context.

For instance a.war would go by default to `/a` context root
and b.war would go to `/b`

so in short, as long as you don't have more than one app that wants to bind to same context root you can have as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only one application can listen on a given port, I'm afraid.

Otherwise, how would your machine know where to send incoming requests?

Comment: thank you sir, I think it can be done by creating multiple instances of server one link is also available but still am not getting process to to this link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293935/jboss-server-with-same-port-on-the-same-machine

Comment: @VirendraKumar you can create multiple instances of the server, certainly, but you won't be able to have them listen on the same port. Your operating system will stop you doing that.

Comment: Sir I am new to this..please provide me complete process for this..and thank you very much

Comment: @VirendraKumar There is no process for it, I'm afraid, because it can't be done. You're trying to do the impossible.